# Scrollable Tabs in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have an Appbar that is getting filled with a list of tabs on creation. How can I make the Tabs horizontally scrollable when they would not fit into the view otherwise?

Is there a Widget I can use?

Comment: Show your tabs' widget code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TabBar have isScrollable parameter. pass true to isScrollable. It will make tabs are scrollable if it will not have enough space.

```
isScrollable: true,
```

Comment: Seems like I missed that part in the documentation